# creating app looking like ICS "Phone" app

Tags: android

I am pretty new at all this android java development to create apps but after a series of tutorial I feel more confident.
I have ideas for an app in which the layout would be like the phone app in android 4.0.3.
Let me explain : my app would.consist in three or four tabs where the user could switch between on to the other by swiping the finger left or right. The top of the layout would display the title of each tab and underline in blue the name current tab (same as the phone app does).
Does anyone have some hints or places where I could find some sample code ? Or even the code of the androidphone app ?

Thank you very much for your help.
David

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/08/11/android-tips-and-tricks-swipey-tabs.html

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537

Is this what You are refering to ?

Comment: Thank you guys this looks pretty much like what i want to do. It is even potentially a bit too fancy for my skills.
I will give it a try once home and let you know if i encounter any problem.

Thanks again.

Comment: Sweet as, accept answer?

If you can't get a hold of me try emailing me instead, not sure if it shows my email or not but its the_smart_lemon@hotmail.co.nz

Comment: @user If this answer solved your problem, be sure to accept it by clicking the green checkmark below its vote count. I'm glad Stack Overflow helped you find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use `ViewPager` and `TitlePageIndicator`.

The `ViewPager` you can find on the compatibility package or on the ActionBarSherlock library (strongly recommend the last one which can be found here http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and `TitlePageIndicator`, found here https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Plus, by using the ViewPager you will learn a bit about Fragments which is very nice :)